# Animate Adobe AIR window height with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, air

Is it possible to animate nativeWindow.stage.stageHeight and nativeWindow.stage.stageWidth wit jQuery's animate() function in Adobe AIR?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Jquery's animate function provides an option called progress (http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> A function to be called after each step of the animation

Inside this function you can set the *nativeWindow.stage.stageHeight* and *nativeWindow.stage.stageWidth* of your app.